# How to get products by manufacturer?

Tags: magento

I want to get list of products which belongs to the selected manufacturer on custom module's frontend. I successfully got the list of manufacturers but I can't retrieve the products related to particular manufacturer. I searched it a lot but I didn't got any solution.

Here is my code 
block file:-

```
public function __construct() 
{
   parent::__construct();
   $brand_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
   $layer = $this->getLayer();
   //$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   $collection = $layer->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
               ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 20);
   $this->setCollection($collection);
}

public function getProductCollection() 
{
   if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) 
   {
      $layer = $this->getLayer();
      //$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
      $collection = $layer->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 20)
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addUrlRewrite();
      $this->_productCollection = $collection;
      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
}

public function getColumnCount() 
{
    return 3;
}
```

and this is my phtml code

```
<?php 

$product = $this->getProductCollection();
foreach ($product as $prods) 
{

 echo '<pre>';  print_r($prods->getData()); die;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above you will need to follow a few steps:

1) Goto Attribute Sets, and make sure "manufacturer" is assigned to the attribute set you are using.

2) Make sure you have added some manufacturers into the attribute options.

3) Assign one of the options to your product.

Depending on your magento version this should work:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

I can see the error you are getting:

gives error Call to a member function getManufacturer() on a non-object in

Are you sure you are putting this code after this line:

```
 <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

Hope this solutions have make you day ....!!!